# Краш при запуске игры с платформой x86_64 на windows 7 x86

Tags: unity3d

Столкнулся с проблемой при сборке игры на PC.

Данные: Windows 7. x86

exe файл собирается с target platform = x86, все запускается и работает, а вот при сборке в x86_64 вылетает

Скриншоты с ошибкой и настройками прикрепил

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Между платформами x86 и x86_64 совместимость только в одну сторону. 32-х битные приложения x86 запускаются на x86_64, обратно - нет.

Comment: Вы хотите сказать сборка с платформой x86_64 на windows x32-bit бит не запустится? x86-64 только для windows x64-bit. Я не пойму почему тогда платформа называется x86-64, а не x64?

Comment: Платформа так называется, чтобы дать покупателю понять, что программы от x86 на ней запустятся. Изначально, она, кстати, называлась AMD64. Вас же, надеюсь, не удивляет, что программы от 486 на самом 86 не запустятся?

Comment: да) уже не удивляет, спасибо